# Encrypt Hibernate dB Password with Spring-Security-Core

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, encryption

I'm running grails 2.3.3 and I've successfully added the spring-security-core, version 2.0-RC5 plugin, into my application.

I have also successfully used the spring-security-core encryption to store encrypted passwords in the hibernate dB. And have also used the isPasswordValid function to check whether passwords match avoiding the need to de-encrypt these passwords.

I would now like to improve the security of my dB further by encrypting the hibernate sa password that logs onto the dB in DataSource.groovy when the application boots up. This however means I need to code (or pipe in from an external file) an encrypted password text string in the DataSource file that gets de-encrypted prior to using it to login to the hibernate dB.

Is there a way in spring-security-core, to de-encrypt a text string - I presume I would need to set an input 'salt' value rather then rely on spring-security-core setting it automatically.

Perhaps there is another way to do this - I would welcome any ideas?

-mike

Comment: What's the purpose of such engine? It probably make dev process harder and if you use two-way encrypting function it'll still be possible to get the password of db. It seems as an illusion of hardening securoty and unnecessary  problem for devs.

Comment: @Michal_Szulc I intend to roll this out into production once I have setup the right level of security.  Protecting the dB login is an imperative - there is an option for me to place the un-encrypted password in a separate file rather than have it hard-coded in the datasource file - but this is still a security risk. One other option I am considering is to input the password at startup - but that would mean manual intervention during startup which is not ideal.